# phonegap 2.0 push notification plugin iOS setup (one error after the other)

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ios6, xcode4.5

Been trying to setup PushNotification with Phonegap 2 base app for the last couple weeks.

Here the steps I have done.

1. Drag the PushNotification folder to the plugins folder:

   [image]
   <sub>(source: [joelchu.com](http://joelchu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/1.png))</sub>
2. Follow the following instruction per documentation

   [image]
   <sub>(source: [joelchu.com](http://joelchu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/2.png))</sub>
3. Add PushNotifcation / PushNotification to the `Cordova.plist` plugins section
4. Modify the `AppDelegate.m`:

   ```
   - (void) dealloc
   {
       [super dealloc];
   }

   /* START PUSH MODIFCATION */

   #pragma PushNotification delegation

   - (void)application:(UIApplication*)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
   {
       PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
       [pushHandler didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
   }

   - (void)application:(UIApplication*)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
   {
       PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
       [pushHandler didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
   }

   - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
   {
       PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
       NSMutableDictionary* mutableUserInfo = [userInfo mutableCopy];

       // Get application state for iOS4.x+ devices, otherwise assume active
       UIApplicationState appState = UIApplicationStateActive;
       if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
           appState = application.applicationState;
       }

       [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"0" forKey:@"applicationLaunchNotification"];
       if (appState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
           [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"1" forKey:@"applicationStateActive"];
           [pushHandler didReceiveRemoteNotification:mutableUserInfo];
       } else {
           [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"0" forKey:@"applicationStateActive"];
           [mutableUserInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] forKey:@"timestamp"];
           [pushHandler.pendingNotifications addObject:mutableUserInfo];
       }
   }

   /* END PUSH MODIFICATION */

   @end
   ```

**FIRST ERROR**

> Unknown type name PushNotification

So I add this line just after the the last import:

```
#import "PushNotification.h"
```

That solves the problem.

**NEXT PROBLEM**

> CDVPlugin.h file not found

So I add the following to User Header Search Paths - to all the build Settings:

```
$(CORDOVALIB)/Classes (recursive)
```

**NEXT PROBLEM**

Then it throws up more than 20 errors!

[image]
<sub>(source: [joelchu.com](http://joelchu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/3.png))</sub>

What have I done wrong?

Been searching up and down everywhere. To my surprise it seems nobody has a problem.

More about my setup:

- Phonegap 2.0
- XCode 4.5 (preview 4)
- iOS 6 base (the app build for iOS 5 and up)

Hope someone out there got an answer. Thank you.

(P.S. if the Phonegap PushNotification plugin is broken - they haven't update for 4 months already. Is there any free alternative? Thanks again)

I described the same problem on [my blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20130120144533/http://joelchu.com:80/phonegap-2-0-pushnotification-plugin-ios-setup-one-error-after-another/).

**FIXED (FOR NOW)**

**FIXED**

```
/* START BLOCK */

#pragma PushNotification delegation

- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
    [pushHandler didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
    [pushHandler didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
    PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
    NSMutableDictionary* mutableUserInfo = [userInfo mutableCopy];

    // Get application state for iOS4.x+ devices, otherwise assume active
    UIApplicationState appState = UIApplicationStateActive;
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
        appState = application.applicationState;
    }

    [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"0" forKey:@"applicationLaunchNotification"];
    if (appState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"1" forKey:@"applicationStateActive"];
        [pushHandler didReceiveRemoteNotification:mutableUserInfo];
    } else {
        [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"0" forKey:@"applicationStateActive"];
        [mutableUserInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] forKey:@"timestamp"];
        [pushHandler.pendingNotifications addObject:mutableUserInfo];
    }
}

/* STOP BLOCK */
```

What I did - the first two

`- (void)application:(UIApplication*)app`

changed to

`- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application`

and I move the

`#import "PushNotification.h"`

to the head of the block (instead of just before the modify code - that cause @end not in context problem).

I haven't run the javascript interface yet. But all the error are gone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to revert your changes to the imports and then replace this block

```
#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
    #import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#else
    #import "CDVPlugin.h"
#endif
```

by this line

```
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
```

If that still does not work, you probably do not have a PhoneGap 2.0 project or you installed the wrong or multiple versions of the framework.

You can do the same in the "PushNotification.m" file: just replace the second import by `#import <Cordova/JSONKit.h>`.

Note that I haven't used that plugin yet, this is just from my experience with porting to 2.0 (I'm the author of the tab/navigation bar plugins).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Did what you said here and the error reduce from 20 to 5. I will update more about the error later.